# Does crossrider method appAPI.db.async works in safari browser?

Tags: cross-browser, safari-extension, crossrider

Im newbie to extension dev in crossrider.
I have written a very simple code snippet , which saves data using appAPI.db.async in extension.js and then retrieves appAPI.db.async in my popup (local file) which we create via browseraction.setPopup.

Save and retrieval of local browser storage works perfectly in FF and chrome . 
But doesnot work in safari.

I even tried appAPI.db method but same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the documentation, all major browsers are supported...nothing in the appAPI.db.async docs says that it has limitations or is unsupported by any browser...and without seeing your code, i'm going to assume its your code. [Here's Crossrider's working demo](http://crossrider.com/apps/12251/ide), how different from that example is your code? or rather, can you implement their code into yours and confirm if it is/not working?

Comment: Ok , i didnt check their demo . If that runs , there's surely a bug in my code